# Load testing in SoapUI with each request having unique credentials

Tags: soapui, load-testing

I need to fire more then 16k request using SoapUI(Load Testing),each request with unique credentials,
Is there any way to test this scenario?

Kindly let me know is it possible with the java script using "setup-script" option in load testing or is there any other way to test?

Cheers!

Comment: Do you use SOAPUI or SOAPUI PRO?

Comment: Where are the credentials?

Comment: Basic "auth" credential option is being used or passing the credentials in the request with WSsecurity element and i want that to be changed for each request automitacally(which can be accomplished by java or groovy script). is it possible this way??

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in groovy script:

```
def tc = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["testSuiteName"].testCases["testCaseName"]
  tc.testSteps.each
  {
   q->
   if(q.getValue().config.type.equals("restrequest") || q.getValue().config.type.equals("request"))
   {
    q.getValue().httpRequest.setUsername("value");
    q.getValue().httpRequest.setPassword("value");
    q.getValue().httpRequest.setDomain("value");
   }
  }
```

You would just need to have the values then set dynamically to be unique.

Comment: hi,thanks a lot but dynamically picking up the values does not work as i need more then 16000 request(which is huge) to be passed with each request having a unique value. so is there anything such which automatically change the number any random number?

Comment: Something like this can be used: `${=(int)(Math.random()*50000)}`